# Flatening a JSONB column into a string in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I am dealing with JSONB columns and its quite new to me.
Below is the sample data set

[image: Sample dataset]

```
UUID    Survey_id   Employee_id Employee_Response   Status
f212    2   17  [{"q_id": "5", "answer": {"value": "Agree"}, "q_type": "radio-buttons"}, {"q_id": "6", "answer": {"value": "4"}, "q_type": "star-ratings"}, {"q_id": "7", "answer": {"value": "9"}, "q_type": "slider-type"}]   active
a3f5    2   46  [{"q_id": "5", "answer": {"value": "Agree"}, "q_type": "radio-buttons"}, {"q_id": "6", "answer": {"value": "4"}, "q_type": "star-ratings"}, {"q_id": "7", "answer": {"value": "8"}, "q_type": "slider-type"}]   active
2db8    2   32  [{"q_id": "5", "answer": {"value": "Agree"}, "q_type": "radio-buttons"}, {"q_id": "6", "answer": {"value": "3"}, "q_type": "star-ratings"}, {"q_id": "7", "answer": {"value": "9"}, "q_type": "slider-type"}]   active
d2bd    2   40  [{"q_id": "5", "answer": {"value": "Disagree"}, "q_type": "radio-buttons"}, {"q_id": "6", "answer": {"value": "2"}, "q_type": "star-ratings"}, {"q_id": "7", "answer": {"value": "3"}, "q_type": "slider-type"}]    active
g632    2   31  [{"q_id": "5", "answer": {"value": "Strongly Agree"}, "q_type": "radio-buttons"}, {"q_id": "6", "answer": {"value": "3"}, "q_type": "star-ratings"}, {"q_id": "7", "answer": {"value": "6"}, "q_type": "slider-type"}]  active
```

Expected output

[image: expected result]

```
UUID    Survey_id   Employee_id Q_5             Q_6     q_7
f212    2           17          Agree           4       9
a3f5    2           46          Agree           4       8
2db8    2           32          Agree           3       9
d2bd    2           40          Disagree        2       3
g632    2           31          Strongly Agree  3       6
```

Can you please suggest or help to achieve the same,
I have tried below and other various methods but still not luck in achieving it in SQL

```
SELECT 
   survey_id, 
   response::jsonb->'answer'->>'value' as name
FROM survey_resposnes

select survey_id,user_id,
response-> 'q_id' @> '[5]' as q0--,
from survey_resposnes
```

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name its 12.5  ( hosted in AWS - RDS )

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jsonb_path_query_first()` for this:

```
select r."uuid", 
       r.survey_id, 
       r.employee_id,
       jsonb_path_query_first(r.employee_response, '$[*] ? (@.q_id == "5").answer.value') #>> '{}' as q_5,
       jsonb_path_query_first(r.employee_response, '$[*] ? (@.q_id == "6").answer.value') #>> '{}' as q_6,
       jsonb_path_query_first(r.employee_response, '$[*] ? (@.q_id == "7").answer.value') #>> '{}' as q_7
from survey_responses r
```

`jsonb_path_query_first()` returns a `jsonb` value. To convert that into a proper `text` value, the `#>> '{}'` is used. If you are fine with a `jsonb` value as the result you can remove that expression

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=51a46b8db492ded6df9975fd7a040e6f)